# Appmaker retrieving records upon user role

Tags: google-app-maker, google-workspace

I am developing a Ticketing system and I have two dashboards for the submitted tickets, one for the admin and the other for the user. The admin should see all the submitted tickets by all users and the user should see only his submitted tickets. I don't know how to retrieve the records upon the user role.

Comment: Do you have a field that records the user's email that submitted the ticket? Are your two separate dashboards based on the same datasource or are you running two separate datasources?

Comment: Yes, I have a record for the user who reported the ticket.Two dashboards for one datasource and every dashboard display different fields.
I want some help in my app as I am stuck in how to do some functionalities in Appmaker. If we can contact I would be very appreciated @MarkusMalessa

Answer (score 0):

How we do it is we use a function to filter the records using the security roles. For example our function uses

```
var user = convertName(app.user.username);
var role = app.user.role;
var ds = app.datasources.DashFilters;
ds.query.clearFilters();
if (!guestBoolean){
  if (role.User || role.Admins){
    ds.query.filters.Roles.name._equals = user;
    ds.query.filters.event_status._notContains = 'Pending';
    ds.query.filters.event_status._notEquals = 'Closed';
  }
  if (role.QADirector){
    ds.query.filters.event_status._notContains = 'Pending';
  }
  }
  if (guestBoolean){
    ds.query.filters.event_status._notContains = 'Pending';
  }
  ds.load();
}
```

The main difference with my function is we have related roles for each record in the data model and that can vary so we check for the current user being a role related to a record. That part is the `!guestBoolean`. The `role.Admins` and `role.QADirector` are using the built in security roles we have assigned to our app.

So in short, query the records using a function which looks for the current logged in user and filter based on your criteria from there.

Comment: Just a side note, but if you have someone that knows what they are doing and they have not so good intentions they can bypass this since it is client side. If you are truly trying to secure records you should implement this via a server script in the datasource or by setting the appropriate security settings in the model itself.

Comment: Thanks Daniel alot. I appreciated. I found an easier way by changing the display of the Panel:Table1Row "the first row in the table" to binding value and put this line @datasource.item.reported_by==@user.email  so it show only the records whose reported by the logged user.